# TeXShop (4.66) preferences not working (Big Sur 11.4)

Tags: texshop, macos

Changes to preferences in TeXShop 4.66 on my newly bought Macbook Air running Big Sur 11.4 don't seem to do anything. I can change all of the settings and seem to be able to save them, but they don't actually change anything. Quitting TeXShop and reopening it doesn't seem to make a difference. Nor does restarting the computer. I'd really like to be able to make a few changes, but I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You mention you've installed the latest version of TeXshop, but you haven't indicated which TeX distribution, if any, you employ. Please clarify.

Comment: FWIW, I also have MacOS 11.4 "Big Sur" and TeXshop 4.66 (along with MacTeX2021), but I experience no problems saving TeXshop preferences. That's why I asked you to provide more information about your computing setup.

Comment: Please try re-booting. Then, before opening TeXShop remove TeXShop.plist found in ~/Library/Preferences. Note: ~/Library is the Library folder in your HOME folder, not /Library which is at the root of your hard drive. To open ~/Library hold the Option key down and click the Go Menu in Finder to see an item to open Library which is the correct folder. Finally start TeXShop to recreate the TeXShop.plist file. See if you can now save Preference changes.

Comment: I am using the latest release of MacTeX. 

Removing the TeXShop.plist file does not seem to do anything. 

To clarify a bit more: I can change some preferences, for example changing the default font and size seems to work fine. But others do nothing, for example setting console to only appear on error does not work, nor does setting the preview window default to multipage (it keeps coming up in double page).

Comment: @Logan_Rah: Setting Console to only show on error means the Console window doesn't come forward while processing not that it never shows unless there is an error. Are you using Single Window Mode or are the Source and Preview in separate windows?

Comment: @Logan_Rah: Also, how are you changing the preference? Changes made using the Preview Menu only hold for the Editing Session; to change the default you must go through the Preview tab of TeXShop->Preferences.